# How to simplify the operator< for a class with some members for the use in std containers

Tags: c++, stl, std

I have a simple class with 4 Ids.

I want to use this class as a key in a `std::map`, `std::set` or any other std container. So I just implemented the `operator<` as seen in the sample code.

The sequence should by like an SQL `ORDER BY m_lIdTicket, m_lIdUser, m_lIdAddress, m_lIdRole`

```
struct S_DATA_CRMTICKETROLES 
{
public:
...
    bool operator<(const S_DATA_CRMTICKETROLES &r) const
    {
        if (m_lIdTicket<r.m_lIdTicket)
            return true;
        else if (m_lIdTicket>r.m_lIdTicket)
            return false;

        if (m_lIdUser<r.m_lIdUser)
            return true;
        else if (m_lIdUser>r.m_lIdUser)
            return false;

        if (m_lIdAddress<r.m_lIdAddress)
            return true;
        else if (m_lIdAddress>r.m_lIdAddress)
            return false;

        if (m_lIdRole<r.m_lIdRole)
            return true;
        else if (m_lIdRole>r.m_lIdRole)
            return false;

        // Seams to be equal. Code placed here if other members are added and to 
        // keep the code in a similar way for each member added.
        return false;
    }
    bool operator==(const S_DATA_CRMTICKETROLES &r) const
    {
        return !operator<(r) && !r.operator<(*this);
    }
    bool operator!=(const S_DATA_CRMTICKETROLES &r) const
    {
        return !operator==(r);
    }
... 
    long m_lIdTicket, m_lIdUser, m_lIdAddress, m_lIdRole;
};
```

Also for convenience and usage in other classes I implemented `operator==` and `operator!=` .

My question: Is there a more effective way to write such code like that?

Comment: In C++20 you can use `= default`, before that `std::tie` would be shorter.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with use `= default`?

Comment: In C++20 compiler can generate definition of operators if you tell it to do so: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) helps before `operator <=>` of C++20 and `bool operator==(const S_DATA_CRMTICKETROLES&) = default`.

```
struct S_DATA_CRMTICKETROLES 
{
public:
    auto as_tuple() const {
        return std::tie(m_lIdTicket, m_lIdUser, m_lIdAddress, m_lIdRole);
    }


    bool operator<(const S_DATA_CRMTICKETROLES &r) const
    {
        return as_tuple() < r.as_tuple();
    }
    bool operator==(const S_DATA_CRMTICKETROLES &r) const
    {
        return as_tuple() == r.as_tuple();
    }
    bool operator!=(const S_DATA_CRMTICKETROLES &r) const
    {
        return as_tuple() != r.as_tuple();
    }
 
    long m_lIdTicket, m_lIdUser, m_lIdAddress, m_lIdRole;
};
```